# Find the count of records by quarter year

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can anyone help me with this?

I need to create a SQL query. I got this table called "slt_especificidade_caso":

[image: slt_especificidade_caso]

I need to create a SQL query which brings me back this structure in 1 row:

**epc_id_pergunta** : the value in column

**first_quarter**: Quantity of registers (eg. number of rows) in this table where the current date less (-) the value in column epc_des_valor is less or equal 90 days

**second_quarter**: Quantity of registers (eg. number of rows) in this table where the current date less (-) the value in column epc_des_valor is more than 90 and less or equal 180 days

**third_quarter**: Quantity of registers (eg. number of rows) in this table where the current date less (-) the value in column epc_des_valor is more than 180 and less than 270 days.

I would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is `epc_idn_tipo_especificidade` the quantity you want to record?

Comment: hello @paqogomez, i didn't understand the question, sorry.

Comment: You say... `Records quantity in this table`  Which column has the quantity you want to record?

Comment: Sorry, i think i expressed myself poorly. What i meant is "Quantity of registers in the table".

Comment: By registers, do you just mean the count of rows?

Comment: Yes @paqogomez, exactly.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect the count instead of the sum of a column

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76211/discussion-between-paqogomez-and-arthur-mastropietro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A case statement should do it.

```
select
  epc_id_pergunta ,
  sum(case when str_to_date(epc_des_valor, '%d/%m/%Y') 
                between DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
                AND CURRENT_DATE()
           then 1 else 0 end) as first_quarter,
  sum(case when str_to_date(epc_des_valor, '%d/%m/%Y') 
                between DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 180 DAY) 
                AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
           then 1 else 0 end) as second_quarter,
  sum(case when str_to_date(epc_des_valor, '%d/%m/%Y') 
                between DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 270 DAY) 
                AND DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 181 DAY) 
           then 1 else 0 end) as third_quarter                      
from
  slt_especificidade_caso
where
  str_to_date(epc_des_valor, '%d/%m/%Y') 
              between DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 270 DAY) 
              AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Check out this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/573b7/3)

Comment: I got this error when running the query:
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'now' in 'field list'. You know what i could possibly doing wrong?

Comment: @ArthurMastropietro, my mistake, `current_date` is the syntax for mysql.

Comment: @ArthurMastropietro are the dates that you are going to deal with in the future or the past?

Comment: Thanks @paqogomez. The sql query is now running ok, but i got all values in first_quarter, second_quarter and third_quarter as 0. Maybe it would be the date format in fleid epc_des_valor?  It´s a string in database (varchar) in format dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Hello @PhilWalton. All the dates recorded in that table (epc_des_valor) are past dates.

Comment: @ArthurMastropietro the reason for that was that I had the larger number (closer date) at the first of the between statements instead of the smaller (further away date)  Its fixed now.  See the fiddle as well.

Comment: Could my epc_des_valor field as a varchar dd/mm/yyyy not doing the sum?